# sorting lines of a text file by number present and output the whole lines in descending order

Tags: java, android, sorting, text-files, scoring

I am trying to make a high score system by saving the names and score to a textfile using this code.

```
String text = name.getText().toString() + " " + score.getText().toString();
            appendLog(text);
        }
    });
}

public void appendLog(String text)
{       
   File logFile = new File("sdcard/logger.file");
   if (!logFile.exists())
   {
      try
      {
         logFile.createNewFile();
      } 
      catch (IOException e)
      {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   try
   {
      //BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag
      BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true)); 
      buf.append(text);
      buf.newLine();
      buf.close();
   }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Is there a way for me to sort the scores present in each line and output name with its corresponding score? Can anyone please help me how to do it? thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Let a row represent your data model, i.e. create a class like `Entry` which will have name and score as its fields. Then you will have a list of these objects. Write a **custom comparator** to sort them in descending order of scores. That's all =)

Comment: can you please give some example for me to understand it better? I'm sorry to say but I am new to java. thank you @Juvanis

Answer (score 0):

As @juvanis said in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15341415/1542438), create a class to represent every record, read the whole file and generate class objects into a list, then sort the list and write the objects in the file in the sorted order.

Here is an example of a class used to represent your record, which consists of a name and a score.

```java
public class Record {

    private int score;
    private String name;

    public getScore () {
        return score;
    }

    public getName () {
        return name;
    }

    public Record ( String name , int score ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }

}
```

In order to sort your file of names and scores, based on the score (I suppose you want to sort the records from the highest score to the lowest) use this method :

```
public void sortFile () {

    // Reference to the file
    File file = new File ( "sdcard/logger.file" );
    // Check if the file exists
    if ( ! file.exists () ) {
        // File does not exists
        return;
    }
    // Check if the file can be read
    if ( ! file.canRead () ) {
        // Cannot read file
        return;
    }
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    // The separator between your name and score
    final String SEPARATOR = " ";
    // A list to host all the records from the file
    List < Record > records = new ArrayList < Record > ();

    try {
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader ( new FileReader ( file ) );
        String line = null;
        // Read the file line by line
        while ( ( line = bufferedReader.readLine () ) != null ) {
            // Skip if the line is empty
            if ( line.isEmpty () )
                continue;
            // Retrieve the separator index in the line
            int separatorIndex = line.lastIndexOf ( SEPARATOR );
            if ( separatorIndex == -1 ) {
                // Separator not found, file is corrupted
                bufferedReader.close ();
                return;
            }
            // Create a record from this line. It is alright if the name contains spaces, because the last space is taking into account
            records.add ( new Record ( line.substring ( 0 , separatorIndex ) , Integer.parseInt ( line.substring ( separatorIndex + 1 , line.length () ) ) ) );
        }
    } catch ( IOException exception ) {
        // Reading error
    } catch ( NumberFormatException exception ) {
        // Corrupted file (score is not a number)
    } finally {
        try {
            if ( bufferedReader != null )
                bufferedReader.close ();
            } catch ( IOException exception ) {
                // Unable to close reader
            }
    }
    bufferedReader = null;

    // Check if there are at least two records ( no need to sort if there are no records or just one)
    if ( records.size () < 2 )
        return;
    // Sort the records
    Collections.sort ( records , new Comparator < Record > () {
            @Override
            public int compare ( Record record1 , Record record2 ) {
            // Sort the records from the highest score to the lowest
                    return record1.getScore () - record2.getScore ();
            }
    } );

    // Replace old file content with the new sorted one
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
    try {
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter ( new FileWriter ( file , false ) ); // Do not append, replace content instead
        for ( Record record : records ) {
            bufferedWriter.append ( record.getName () + SEPARATOR + record.getScore () );
            bufferedWriter.newLine ();
        }
        bufferedWriter.flush ();
        bufferedWriter.close ();
    } catch ( IOException exception ) {
        // Writing error
    } finally {
        try {
            if ( bufferedWriter != null )
                bufferedWriter.close ();
        } catch ( IOException exception ) {
            // Unable to close writer
        }
    }
    bufferedWriter = null;

    // You can output the records, here they are displayed in the log
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < records.size () ; i ++ )
        Log.d ( "Record number : " + i , "Name : \"" + records.get ( i ).getName () + "\" , Score : " + records.get ( i ).getScore () );

}
```

If there is something you did not understand, please let me know.
Try it and keep me up-to-date if it works fine as you intended.